# How can I write this code in only one line (three lines total)?

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, output

The code is:

```
function [w]= example1(v)
 w=[];
 for i= 1:length(v)
   if v(i) ~=2
     w= [w,0];
   else
     w=[w,10];
   end
end
```

I want to know how I can manipulate my code so that it can all fit in one line without the use of and loops or if statements (in total three lines considering function line and end).
Also the input is a row vector.

Comment: Use vector operations rather than loops.

Comment: It's was a practice problem and I wrote the code above but then was told that it can be written in one line so I'm trying to figure out how

Comment: Start with this `w = (v ~= 2)` and see if you can go from there.

Comment: Oh i see that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the single condition `v ~= 2` you could do something like this:

First create an empty array of zeros and then add 10s where `v == 2`.

```
v = [1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2];
w = zeros(size(v)) + (v == 2) * 10;
```

Take a look at the documentation for [logical operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) for further information.